# PrimeNG grouped multiselect is selecting items from other group

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG to create a multi-select dropdown in an Angular application as in the snippet below:
The problem I seem to be having, is the groups all have same names, and selecting one, selects them all.

```html
<p-multiSelect [options]="groupedInteractions" [group]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedInteractions" defaultLabel="Select" formControlName="interactions">
</p-multiSelect>
```

```
Json is similar to this:


{
"First-Group": [
    "Self-service",
    "Non self-service"
],
"Second-Group": [
    "Self-service",
    "Non self-service"
]
```

}

If I select "Self Service" From First group.
Both "Self Services" are selected.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a unique attribute in the object that identifies each element, and use the optionValue and optionLabel properties:
{
"First-Group": [
"Self-service",
"Non self-service",
1
],
"Second-Group": [
"Self-service",
"Non self-service",
2
]
}